# How to determine version Intel Management Engine on Linux?

Tags: linux, intel-core-i7

I just heard about the [latest Intel ME disclosure](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14241241). I'd like to update my firmware, but I don't use Windows/OSX. How can I find out what version of Intel ME I have and how do I update it?

Comment: You can download the current version of [Intel Management Engine](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=Management+Engine) on Linux and Windows from Intel directly.

Comment: @Ramhound could you elaborate? At this point it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: The current version of the firmware can be downloaded from Intel.  I was able to select Redhat 7.3 and download the current version without a problem

Comment: Worth pointing out the exploit was only applicable to the Windows driver

Comment: On some configurations the version is reported [here](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-5693)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now [mjg59's mei-amt-check](https://github.com/mjg59/mei-amt-check) seems to be the best answer to this problem ([found on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14335159)).

Answer (score 6):

Use the official Intel tool.

You can download it following this link: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025619/software.html

extract the archive and execute the python script as root

```
sudo python2 intel_sa00086.py
```

**NB:** first, you have to be root (*sudo*); second, the tool is compatible with version 2 of python (*python2*).

Comment: Is it safe to run intel stuff as root?

Comment: Why should not?

Comment: Not knowing what you run as root should be concerning...

Comment: Ah, ok! Your is a privacy/security issue. 1) It's a python script, you can (at least partially) decode what it will do 2) It's an official tool from Intel, shared by many vendors

Comment: @mattia.b89 a little gripe about your 2nd point, Intel and security are 2 contradicting topics, it's right to be concerned Intel might've written a poor/malicious patch since they do a bad job on their CPUs as well as maliciously overprice them.

Answer (score 3):

I found a couple of ways to get ME version without Windows

1) BIOS settings 
If your system is not a critical server you can reboot it and check BIOS settings. Some ASUS boards and all Supermicro boards does display ME version.

2) UEFITool 
ME version could be extracted from firmware file. Download firmware file from vendor's site and use UEFITool to open it, look for 'ME region'.

https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool

Management Engine usually updated along with BIOS firmware. Check vendor's site or ask support for updated version.

Answer (score 2):

### Quick way (`python` must be running as root):

```
$ sudo python
from heci import get_fw_state
print get_fw_state()
```

### Official Intel check (for latest [CVE-2017-5705](https://security-center.intel.com/advisory.aspx?intelid=intel-sa-00086&languageid=en-fr)):

1. Download Linux [Intel-SA-00086 Detection Tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27150)
2. `mkdir -p ~/src/pub/security/Intel-SA-00086 && cd ~/src/pub/security/Intel-SA-00086`
3. `tar -C ~/src/pub/security/Intel-SA-00086 -xvf  ~/Downloads/SA00086_Linux.tar.gz`
4. `sudo ./intel_sa00086.py`

If `/dev/mei*` devices are not found:

- `sudo modprobe mei`
- Re-run the check script.

Answer (score 0):

What about the intelmetool from coreboot?

```
git clone http://review.coreboot.org/coreboot.git coreboot

cd coreboot/util/intelmetool
make
su - root
./intelmetool -m -d
```

if lucky

```
./intelmetool -d -m
Error CPU is not from Intel.: Success
```

if a less lucky

```
./intelmetool -d -m
ME PCI device is hidden
RCBA addr: 0x00000000
Can't find ME PCI device
```

if REALLY unlucky

```
./intelmetool -d -m

Bad news, you have a `8 Series LPC Controller` so you have ME hardware on board and you can't control or disable it, continuing...

MEI found: [*****:****] 8 Series HECI #0

ME Status   : 0x********
ME Status 2 : 0x********

ME: FW Partition Table      : OK
ME: Bringup Loader Failure  : NO
ME: Firmware Init Complete  : YES
ME: Manufacturing Mode      : NO
ME: Boot Options Present    : NO
ME: Update In Progress      : NO
ME: Current Working State   : Normal
ME: Current Operation State : M0 with UMA
ME: Current Operation Mode  : Normal
ME: Error Code              : No Error
ME: Progress Phase          : Host Communication
ME: Power Management Event  : Clean Moff->Mx wake
ME: Progress Phase State    : Host communication established

PCI READ [bc] : 0x********
ME: Extend SHA-256: ****************

WRITE READ messages....

ME Capability: Full Network manageability                 : ON
ME Capability: Regular Network manageability              : ON
ME Capability: Manageability                              : ON
ME Capability: Small business technology                  : ON
ME Capability: Level III manageability                    : ON
ME Capability: IntelR Anti-Theft (AT)                     : ON
ME Capability: IntelR Capability Licensing Service (CLS)  : ON
ME Capability: IntelR Power Sharing Technology (MPC)      : ON
ME Capability: ICC Over Clocking                          : ON
ME Capability: Protected Audio Video Path (PAVP)          : ON
ME Capability: IPV6                                       : ON
ME Capability: KVM Remote Control (KVM)                   : ON
ME Capability: Outbreak Containment Heuristic (OCH)       : ON
ME Capability: Virtual LAN (VLAN)                         : ON
ME Capability: TLS                                        : ON
ME Capability: Wireless LAN (WLAN)                        : ON
```

To avoid ME when is possible buy Open-ppc (really expensive!), another good choice is Intel+Coreboot but before buy take info about the possibility of disable IME